# Obtaining real device of VLAN-interface through the netlink

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, netlink, vlan

I need to obtain the [`real_dev`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.172/source/net/8021q/vlan.h#L29) (f.e. ID) of the given VLAN-inteface.

I wrote some test snippet using [*libnl*](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/):

```
int main(void) {
     struct nl_sock *sock;
     struct nl_cache *cache;
     char iface[] = "eno1.10";
     //char iface[] = "eno1";

     if (!(sock = nl_socket_alloc())) {
          perror("nl_socket_alloc");
          return -1; 
     }

     if (nl_connect(sock, NETLINK_ROUTE) < 0) {
          perror("nl_connect");
          nl_socket_free( sock );
          return -1; 
     }

     if (rtnl_link_alloc_cache(sock, AF_UNSPEC, &cache) < 0) {
          perror("rtnl_link_alloc_cache");
          nl_socket_free( sock );
          nl_close( sock );
          return -1; 
     }
     {   
          int ifindex; 
          struct rtnl_link *link = NULL;

          if (!(ifindex = rtnl_link_name2i(cache, iface))) {
               perror("rtnl_link_name2i");
               return -1; 
          }
          printf("ind: %d\n", ifindex);

          if (!(link = rtnl_link_get(cache, ifindex))) {
               perror("rtnl_link_get");
               return -1; 
          }

          if (rtnl_link_is_vlan(link)) {
               puts("It's VLAN link");

               /* alas it's not about the 'real' device */
               printf("master: %d\n", rtnl_link_get_master(link));
          } else
               puts("It's 'real' link");
     }   

     return 0;
}
```

So I have some *interface ID* and I can check if it's a VLAN-interface, but I have no idea ***how to obtain the interface the vlan is attached to***.
It seems that *libnl*'s API does not provide such possibility.

Is there a way to obtain the VLAN's "parent" interface ID through the *libnl* or the *native netlink API*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about [`IFLA_LINK`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/uapi/linux/if_link.h#L111):

```
/* IFLA_LINK.
   For usual devices it is equal ifi_index.
   If it is a "virtual interface" (f.e. tunnel), ifi_link
   can point to real physical interface (f.e. for bandwidth calculations),
   or maybe 0, what means, that real media is unknown (usual
   for IPIP tunnels, when route to endpoint is allowed to change)
 */
```

Thus through the *native netlink API* it could be done such a way:

```
/* some preparation code */
struct rtattr *rta = IFLA_RTA(msg);
int len = nh->nlmsg_len - NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*msg));
for (; RTA_OK(rta, len); rta = RTA_NEXT(rta, len))
    if (rta->rta_type == IFLA_LINK) {
        printf("Real device ID:%u\n",
               *(unsigned short *)((char *) rta + NLA_HDRLEN));
        break;
    }
```

[Full example on github](https://github.com/red0ct/network-sketches/blob/master/usermode/nl_parentdev.c).